# D3 adding 19 hours when it formats time

Tags: javascript, date, d3.js, format

I'm trying to convert a value in seconds returned by the database into a date object, and then pass it to the D3 format method. But when I try and format any time, d3's formatting function is adding 19 hours to my time! For instance, passing 0 to the date object, like this:

```
// create the third column for each segment.
tr.append("td").attr("class",'legendFreq')
    .text(function(d){ return d3.time.format("%H:%M:%S")(new Date(0));});
```

returns `19:0:0`

Anybody know what's happening here?

Comment: That returns the current time, without the offset. Using Date('string') and Date(year,month,day,hour,min,sec) work normally as well. But I'm wondering why I can't get the milliseconds Date functionality working without this huge offset - when I use 12 hour time in the format function instead of 24, it gives a 7 hour offset? I'm just super confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

d3 is not adding the hours, the difference is based on the timezone.

`new Date(0)` by default returns a timezone dependent date object.
(For me it is `Thu Jan 01 1970 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (W. Europe Standard Time)`)

If I use your d3.format function I get (correctly) only the hour part: `"01:00:00"`.

To make your timestamp timezone-independent, you should use the [d3.time.format.utc](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting#format_utc) function. Using that, I get `"00:00:00"`:

```
d3.time.format.utc("%H:%M:%S")(new Date(0))
```